# How to configure sitecore DAM in sitecore Instance?

Tags: dam

I installed  Sitecore Connect for Sitecore DAM 2.0 in sitecore 9.2 Instance. After that I don't know how to configure CORS Confiuration in sitecore content hub.

Could you please tell how to configure CORS Configuration in Sitecore Content Hub?

Answer (score 2):

**Content Hub Configuration**

To allow a Sitecore instance to access content hub, you must add a CORS configuration entry with your Sitecore CM instance URL.

1. Navigate to: Manage -> Settings -> PortalConfiguration ->CORSConfiguration or go to URL>  http://CONTENT_HUB_URL/en-us/admin/settingmanagement?setting=CORSConfiguration&settingId=8748
2. Enter your CM instance URL (e.g. http://sc92.dev.local) and click
   Save.

Source from [here](https://josedbaez.com/2019/08/sitecore-content-hub-dam-connector/)

Comment: Where do I Find the Navigation part: Manage -> Settings -> PortalConfiguration -> CORSConfiguration ? and What I have to replace in CONTENT_HUB_URL in the given url. Is it Sitecore Instance URL?

Answer (score 0):

There is a video on Master SItecore which shows you a walkthrough for installing and configuring the DAM plugin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRy6Oyvtrs8

Most steps should still be applicable in 9.2. This may help you with knowing where to go to find things.

The official documentation for installation and configuration is available on [dev.sitecore.net](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Plugin_for_Stylelabs_DAM/20/Sitecore_Connect_for_Sitecore_DAM_200.aspx)

Assuming you have DAM 3.3.0, the steps for configuring CORS in that documentation (section 1.1.1):

> 1. Go to **Manage** (Main menu item).
> 2. Click on the **Settings** item.
> 3. On the Settings page, click on the **PortalConfiguration** menu item.
> 4. Click on **CORSConfiguration** under the **PortalConfiguration** menu item.
> 5. Add the Sitecore instance URL to the list of URLs (e.g. https://www.sitecore.instance.com).
> 6. Save the changes.

Comment: What is DAM 3.3.0 in the context ? I am not getting DAM 3.3.0 package anywhere. I dont   know where I have to configure the CORS configuration.In my sitecore Instance There is no Manage in Main menu item . Could you please tell where I have to configure the CORS configuration

Comment: When you use the DAM connector, you are connecting it to your DAM (Sitecore Content Hub). The instructions above are from within your Sitecore Content Hub instance.

Sitecore Content Hub has different versions, and 3.3.0 is the version of the DAM. You may have a different version, you need to look at the instructions that are valid for your version.

If you watch the video, you will be able to see the difference between what you do in Content Hub, and what you do in Sitecore, to connect the two together.